# View twitter comments in html

Tags: html, url, twitter, comments

I am trying to view Twitter comments in the source html,

however on viewing, the comments are not present,

I know I can view them using `jquery` but is there an alternative way of changing the url so that I can view the comments in the source? As I am using an application that is dependant on the url being hard coded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking of twitters official site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *comments* you mean *statuses*, they're hidden under the `data-` attributes of various elements.  You should consider using the official API instead: https://dev.twitter.com/.

If you really, really can't do that, you could try the [mobile version](http://mobile.twitter.com/); however, you should **never** rely on parsing sites when there is an API available.